# Error: csv.Error: field larger than field limit (131072)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un programa que abre csv files, opera con frases y graba datos en otro csv file.

Estoy obteniendo ahora un error que jamás antes había obtenido. He rastreado internet en busca de soluciones pero no encuentro mucho.

El error es el siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/file.py", line 222, in <module>
    sents, tagged_sents = tag_read_sentences()
  File "C:/Users/file.py", line 130, in wrapper
    value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/file.py", line 201, in tag_read_sentences
    sents = read_input_sentences()
  File "C:/Users/file.py", line 148, in read_input_sentences
    for row_i, row in enumerate(reader):
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\csv.py", line 111, in __next__
    self.fieldnames
  File "C:\Python36-32\lib\csv.py", line 98, in fieldnames
    self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)
_csv.Error: field larger than field limit (131072)
```

Agradezco la ayuda, como siempre. Cruzo los dedos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que el tamaño de los campos de un `csv` tiene un límite por defecto, que eventualmente puedes consultar y/o configurar usando [`field_size_limit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.field_size_limit). Puedes ampliar dicho límite por ejemplo de la siguiente forma:

```
import csv

csv.field_size_limit(300000)
```